# i'm trying to keep my webview hidden till the URL is finished loading

Tags: javascript, webview, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that loads an external site into a webview, I see a blank page each time the webview is loaded before the url is finished loading. I would like the webview to show only after the url is done loading. I also have an eventlistener for loadstart, that is meant to close the window when that url is hit and return to the ionic app homescreen, this works on my emulator but on my real device it just shows a blank page with symbols.

```
   $scope.login = function()
      {
        //check if network is connected before sending initial request
        if(monitor.isOffline())
        {
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Network Error!',
            template: "Your Network is Offline, please connect and try again"
          });
        }

        //show spinner while loading page
        $scope.show = function() {
          $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
          });
        };

        //hide spinner
        $scope.hide = function(){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        };


        //send initial request
        AuthService.login($scope.user).then(
          function(home)
          {
            $scope.show($ionicLoading);
            if(monitor.isOnline())
            {
              $scope.show($ionicLoading);

              var ref = window.open(home, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

              ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event)
              {
                if(event.url == "http://mobile.map.education/logout" )
                {
                  ref.close();
                }

              });
              ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function (event)
              {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Network Error',
                  template: "Oops,Error with your network"
                });

                ref.close();

              });

              $scope.hide($ionicLoading);

              //watch network state
              monitor.startWatching();
            }
            if(monitor.isOffline())
            {
              var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Network Error',
                template: "Oops,Error with your network"
              })
            }
          },
          function (errMsg)
          {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Login failed!',
              template: errMsg
            });
          })
          .catch(function()
          {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Login failed!',
              template: 'Server not responding'
            })
              .finally(function ($ionicLoading)
              {
                $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
              });
          });
      };
```

Comment: You want to keep `ref` window hidden until the page is loaded?

Comment: yes, i want to keep ref hidden

Answer (score 0):

I think this working only with `InAppBrowserPlugin` but you can open the window with `hidden=yes`

```
var ref = window.open(home, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,hidden=yes');
```

then:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
   ref.show();
});
```

check the doc here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/